# MKMapView userLocation wrong on iOS5 but correct on iOS4.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, mapkit

I'm finding that `MKMapView` userLocation returns the wrong location on iOS 5.0.1 but the right location for iOS 4.2.1. Both the blue dot and the value passed to delegate method `didUpdateUserLocation` are consistent with property userLocation (and hence also wrong on iOS5).

Oddly the wrong location is consistently just off Regents Circus in London (60 miles away from my actual location).

These results are from running on an iPhone 3GS and iPhone 4, both with Location Services enabled.

Anyone experience similar strangeness?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to rule this out, are you building these off the simulator using Xcode 4.2?  If so you may have set the schema you are using to have a default location. If you open Edit Schema you can check it out under Options.

Comment: I think that could well be it. Thanks!